# Resizing table columns, that can be hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, resize, hidden

I have a standard table with option to hide columns and I want to use a plugin for re-sizing the width of the columns.

I tried with ***colResizable*** and ***resizableColumns*** but the things get messy when I hide a column and then try re-sizing.

***Edit:*** My table:

```
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
    <tr><th class="column1"></th>text 1 <th class="column2">text 2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="column1"> cell00 </td> <td class="column2"> cell01 </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="column1"> cell10 </td> <td class="column2"> cell11 </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="column1"> cell20 </td> <td class="column2"> cell21 </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Activating ***colResizable***:

```
$("#mytable").colResizable({
    liveDrag:false, 
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging",
    minWidth:50         
});
```

Function for hidding / displaying columns:

```
function toggleColumn(index){
    if(something){
        $('.column'+index).hide();
    }else{
        $('.column'+index).show();
    }
$("#"+tableID).colResizable({
    disable:true
});                                             
$("#"+tableID).colResizable({
    disable:false,
    liveDrag:false, 
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging",
    minWidth:50         
});
}
```

After each toggle i restart *colResizable*, so it can get the new values.

The problem comes when I re-size any columns beyond the hidden ones.

I also need the option to set default widths to each column. All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Please post your revelant code.

Comment: All of your attempts and code are welcomed too ;)

Answer (score 2):

colResizable 1.5 is compatible with hidden columns. You can download it on http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable

if you want to change column visibility after colResizable is already activated, those are the steps you have to follow:

1. call colResizable (as usual)
2. before you perform any DOM modifications (such as hiding a column), destroy colresizable using disable:true
3. change columns visibility
4. call colResizable again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) has everything you may want.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/d34YM/show/). You get everything: Show, hide columns, resized columns, and many more cool options. And using it is very easy

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "option": value;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: This is nice, but I have another menu for hidding columns (and other things) so all I need is a re-size function that works for my table.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:

Use a class name on the TD. Give the class name in a style element that is added dynamically to the document. To resize, delete the style element from the document then add again with new specifics.

option 2:

Cycle through the rows collection of the table setting style.width on .cells[0], .cells[1], ....
To hide, set style.display to none, then to unhide, inline.